# Oracle min and max (same values)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
select min(price),
       max(price),
       name       
from Table1
group by name
```

As a result I get table with:

**name | minimal(price) | maximum(price)**

but I also get rows where price is the same. How to fix it? (I don't need rows with same value)

Comment: group by name , price

Answer (score 8):

Use `having`:

```
select min(price), max(price), name
from Table1 
group by name
having max(price) != min(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I got it right one name field has 2 same fields of price in result query.

```
    select min(price),
           max(price),
           name       
    from Table1
    group by name, price
```

Comment: Will not return the wanted result.